# "Indiana Jones"/As the crow flies style google map plotting, no animation?

Tags: google-maps

Given a set of GPS coordinates, I need to plot them using Google maps and draw a line from each one to the next.  It would be optimal if I could show directionality, but that's not absolutely necessary as long as I can indicate the start point.

There will be more than two points -- the number of points requested will vary, so I guess I need to know the max number of points I can plot on a single map so, if needed, I can break the points into multiple maps.

I don't care about distance.

I don't care about true accuracy -- these are just to help the user visualize the places an object has been.

Nor do I need any kind of information returned except the map.  It would be nice to embed the returned map on a web page, but I'll accept sending the user off to Google Maps.

I suspect there's a API out here to do this, but a bunch of searching didn't provide any results, so any help would be appreciated.

Sean.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [KML file and display it on Google maps](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2006/11/kml-on-google-maps.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/time.html) will help, it is the reference about animation in KML. I believe you will want Example: Animating Ground Overlays .